# How to pandas read log file after specific text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a log file. I should simplify and export it to excel file. There is a specific text in this log file. I need data after this text. How can I read and export this log file?

```
Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    4.89 sec. (2902.79 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 4 threads:
  Real time             =   96.05 sec. (38798.86 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    5.63 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.01 sec.
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) =  100.94 sec. (41701.65 ticks)

Solution pool: 8 solutions saved.

MIP - Integer optimal solution:  Objective =  1.1401550956e+03
Solution time =  100.94 sec.  Iterations = 501135  Nodes = 2819
Deterministic time = 41701.69 ticks  (413.12 ticks/sec)


Incumbent solution
Variable Name           Solution Value
x4_5_14                       1.000000
x4_5_24                       1.000000
x4_5_34                       1.000000
x4_5_52                       1.000000
x4_5_82                       1.000000
x4_5_106                      1.000000
x4_5_118                      1.000000
x4_5_142                      1.000000
x4_5_154                      1.000000
x4_6_19                       1.000000
x4_6_29                       1.000000
x4_6_40                       1.000000
x4_6_58                       1.000000
x4_6_88                       1.000000
x4_6_112                      1.000000
x4_6_124                      1.000000
x4_6_148                      1.000000
x4_6_160                      1.000000
x5_5_9                        1.000000
x5_5_19                       1.000000
x5_5_29                       1.000000
x5_5_46                       1.000000
x5_5_58                       1.000000
x5_5_70                       1.000000
x5_5_94                       1.000000
x5_5_130                      1.000000
x5_5_142                      1.000000
x5_5_154                      1.000000
x5_5_166                      1.000000
x5_5_178                      1.000000
x5_6_14                       1.000000
x5_6_24                       1.000000
x5_6_34                       1.000000
x5_6_52                       1.000000
x5_6_64                       1.000000
x5_6_76                       1.000000
x5_6_100                      1.000000
x5_6_136                      1.000000
x5_6_148                      1.000000
x5_6_160                      1.000000
x5_6_172                      1.000000
x5_6_184                      1.000000
x9_5_4                        1.000000
x9_5_14                       1.000000
x9_5_29                       1.000000
x9_5_40                       1.000000
x9_5_64                       1.000000
x9_5_76                       1.000000
x9_5_88                       1.000000
x9_5_100                      1.000000
x9_5_112                      1.000000
x9_5_124                      1.000000
x9_5_136                      1.000000
x9_5_148                      1.000000
x9_5_160                      1.000000
x9_5_172                      1.000000
x9_6_9                        1.000000
x9_6_19                       1.000000
x9_6_34                       1.000000
x9_6_46                       1.000000
x9_6_70                       1.000000
x9_6_82                       1.000000
x9_6_94                       1.000000
x9_6_106                      1.000000
x9_6_118                      1.000000
x9_6_130                      1.000000
x9_6_142                      1.000000
x9_6_154                      1.000000
x9_6_166                      1.000000
x9_6_178                      1.000000
x11_1_12                      1.000000
x11_1_24                      1.000000
x11_1_40                      1.000000
x11_1_60                      1.000000
x11_1_83                      1.000000
x11_1_105                     1.000000
x11_1_128                     1.000000
x11_1_140                     1.000000
x11_1_154                     1.000000
x11_2_19                      1.000000
x11_2_32                      1.000000
x11_2_52                      1.000000
x11_2_72                      1.000000
x11_2_94                      1.000000
x11_2_116                     1.000000
x11_2_135                     1.000000
x11_2_148                     1.000000
x11_2_162                     1.000000
x17_1_30                      1.000000
x17_1_136                     1.000000
x17_2_37                      1.000000
x17_2_142                     1.000000
x18_1_10                      1.000000
x18_1_23                      1.000000
x18_1_36                      1.000000
x18_1_56                      1.000000
x18_1_76                      1.000000
x18_1_99                      1.000000
x18_1_121                     1.000000
x18_1_137                     1.000000
x18_1_149                     1.000000
x18_1_184                     1.000000
x18_1_196                     1.000000
x18_1_208                     1.000000
x18_2_17                      1.000000
x18_2_30                      1.000000
x18_2_48                      1.000000
x18_2_68                      1.000000
x18_2_88                      1.000000
x18_2_110                     1.000000
x18_2_131                     1.000000
x18_2_143                     1.000000
x18_2_156                     1.000000
x18_2_190                     1.000000
x18_2_202                     1.000000
x18_2_214                     1.000000
x23_1_17                      1.000000
x23_1_30                      1.000000
x23_1_153                     1.000000
x23_2_24                      1.000000
x23_2_37                      1.000000
x23_2_159                     1.000000
x27_1_7                       1.000000
x27_1_19                      1.000000
x27_1_32                      1.000000
x27_1_48                      1.000000
x27_1_68                      1.000000
x27_1_89                      1.000000
x27_1_131                     1.000000
x27_1_143                     1.000000
x27_1_157                     1.000000
x27_1_170                     1.000000
x27_1_202                     1.000000
x27_2_14                      1.000000
x27_2_26                      1.000000
x27_2_40                      1.000000
x27_2_60                      1.000000
x27_2_80                      1.000000
x27_2_100                     1.000000
x27_2_137                     1.000000
x27_2_150                     1.000000
x27_2_165                     1.000000
x27_2_176                     1.000000
x27_2_208                     1.000000
x32_1_19                      1.000000
x32_1_33                      1.000000
x32_1_137                     1.000000
x32_1_153                     1.000000
x32_2_26                      1.000000
macost52                      8.710800
macost60                     54.797800
macost                      599.535600
dricost4                     16.339460
dricost5                     21.878260
dricost9                     25.201540
dricost11                    21.324380
dricost17                     3.877160
dricost18                    26.309300
dricost23                     6.369620
dricost27                    24.924600
dricost32                     8.862080
dricost40                    22.432140
dricost41                     2.492460
dricost43                    21.324380
dricost45                     9.969840
dricost46                    13.293120
dricost47                    11.908420
dricost52                     3.877160
dricost60                    23.539900
dricost                     263.923820
tmil4                       115.290000
tmil5                       153.720000
tmil9                       179.340000
tmil11                      138.150000
tmil17                       30.700000
tmil18                      184.200000
tmil23                       46.050000
tmil27                      168.850000
tmil32                       61.400000
tmil40                      153.500000
tmil41                       15.350000
tmil43                      138.150000
tmil45                       61.400000
tmil46                       92.100000
tmil47                       76.750000
tmil52                       25.620000
tmil60                      168.850000
tmil                       1809.420000
ttime4                      295.000000
ttime5                      395.000000
ttime9                      455.000000
ttime11                     385.000000
ttime17                      70.000000
ttime18                     475.000000
ttime23                     115.000000
ttime27                     450.000000
ttime32                     160.000000
ttime40                     405.000000
ttime41                      45.000000
ttime43                     385.000000
ttime45                     180.000000
ttime46                     240.000000
ttime47                     215.000000
ttime52                      70.000000
ttime60                     425.000000
ttime                      4765.000000
tboar                     10275.000000
nbus                         34.000000
All other variables matching '*' are 0.
```

I need data after "MIP-Integer optimal solution" line. I would like to extract Objective, Solution Time, Iterations, Nodes, Deterministic Time and data below 'Incumbent solution' text.

I tried this.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import os
x = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser('G1/Cplex_Cng12/RGroup1_cng12.log'), usecols=[0])
print(x[135:])
```

But the number of lines in upper part of required text is not same. So i could not use skiprows function. I need to simplify this and use only data under 'Incumbent solution' text. And also need to get objective, solution time, iterations and deterministic time values. They are in same line. I need to seperate these values.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I stuck while reading log file. I tried that x = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser('G1/Cplex_Cng12/RGroup1_cng12.log'), usecols=[0]). But i could not find how I can choose lines after specific line named as Incumbent solution.

Comment: Read the data in as a string, clean your input, then pass the cleaned input to `pandas` to read.

Comment: Is the number of lines fixed in the top part of the file? Also, pandas might be helpful to extract the data below "Incumbent solution", but you should extract text directly for the "MIP - Integer optimal solution" lines.

Comment: @mozway the lines is not fixed. All log files have different number of lines. If not i can use skiprows. But this is not possible in that files. I can extract text directly, but there is 200 log file. So i need to write a code to do this.

Comment: @Harun Horasanlı you can test my solution, it might not work for all files depending on how variable the format is. If this is the case, please post non working examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the file on reliable delimiters. Here I chose `MIP - Integer optimal solution`, `\n`, `Incumbent solution`, and `All other variables matching` as delimiters. You might need to adapt the code if those are not reliable.

Full code:

```
import re, io

start_collecting_annotations = False
start_collecting_data = False
annotations_lines = []
data_lines = []
with open('/tmp/log.txt') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line == '':  # if no more lines to read, stop
            break
        if line.startswith('MIP - Integer optimal solution'):
            start_collecting_annotations = True
        if line.startswith('Incumbent solution'):
            start_collecting_data = True
        if start_collecting_annotations:  # here we collect the annotations
            if line == '\n':
                start_collecting_annotations = False
            else:
                annotations_lines.append(line)
        if start_collecting_data:        # here we collect the data
            if line.startswith('All other variables matching'):
                break
            else:
                data_lines.append(line)

annotations = pd.Series(dict([re.split('\s+=\s+', i)
                              for i in re.findall(r'(?:[^\s]+ )?[^\s]+\s+=\s+[^\s]+',
                                                  ' '.join(annotations_lines))
                             ])).astype(float)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(''.join(data_lines[1:])), sep='\s\s+', index_col=[0])
```

output:

```
>>> annotations

Objective               1140.155096
Solution time            100.940000
Iterations            501135.000000
Nodes                   2819.000000
Deterministic time     41701.690000
dtype: float64

>>> df.head()

               Solution Value
Variable Name                
x4_5_14                   1.0
x4_5_24                   1.0
x4_5_34                   1.0
x4_5_52                   1.0
x4_5_82                   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "barbaric" way to do this, many would not complain, but hey, it works:

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep='\t')

for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[f'{list(data.columns)[0]}'][i][0:3] == 'MIP':
        Objective = float(data[f'{list(data.columns)[0]}'][i][46:62])
        Solution_time = float(data[f'{list(data.columns)[0]}'][i+1][17:23])
        Iteration = int(data[f'{list(data.columns)[0]}'][i+1][43:49])
        Nodes = int(data[f'{list(data.columns)[0]}'][i+1][59:64])
        Deterministic_time = float(data[f'{list(data.columns)[0]}'][i+2][21:29])
        break
print(Objective, Solution_time, Iteration, Nodes, Deterministic_time)
```

test.txt is your above data, I just copied it into a txt.

Comment: thanks for your help. I copy and paste this. I run it. It gave an error. KeyError: 'Root node processing (before b&c):'

Comment: replace `'Root node processing (before b&c):'` with `f'{list(data.columns)[0]}'`, then it should work

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution in another way, I've created a .txt file that has data as you've mentioned. I upload it to python then I create excel and then I read it and create two data frames, one is for head data and the second is for the tail. I know it is not the most efficient way but I am still learning :)

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet('First Sheet')
f = open('tekst.txt', 'r+')
data = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(data)):
  row = data[i].split()
  for j in range(len(row)):
    ws.write(i, j, row[j])
#Creation Excel
book.save('Excelfile' + '.xls')
f.close()
#Write Excel and modify data
df = pd.read_excel('Excelfile.xls')
df = df[['Root', 'node', 'processing', '(before', 'b&c):']]
df = df[10:]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Col_1',df.columns[1]: 'Col_2',df.columns[2]: 'Col_3',df.columns[3]: 'Col_4',df.columns[4]: 'Col_5'})
df_head = df[0:3].reset_index(drop=True)
df_bottom = df[7:].reset_index(drop=True)
df_bottom = df_bottom[['Col_1','Col_2']]
df.rename(columns={df_bottom.columns[0]: 'Variable Name',df_bottom.columns[1]: 'Solution Value'})
```

And the output is like this:

```
df_bottom
       Col_1     Col_2
0    x4_5_14  1.000000
1    x4_5_24  1.000000
2    x4_5_34  1.000000
3    x4_5_52  1.000000
```

```
df_head
           Col_1 Col_2    Col_3     Col_4      Col_5
0            MIP     -  Integer   optimal  solution:
1       Solution  time        =    100.94       sec.
2  Deterministic  time        =  41701.69      ticks
```

I hope I could help